# Jacobi Iterative Method. (Help me with the output)

Tags: c++, c, iteration

The problem is the output should show the value of `x`,`y` and `z` from the first iteration until the last iteration where `big` is less than or equal to `e`. But the problem is it is only showing the last iteration. How do I output the other iterations?
 Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    float a[50][50],x[50],e=0.0010,big,temp,relerror,sum;
    int n=3,i,j,maxit=50,itr;
    char ch;
    clrscr();
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("\n\t\t\t  ----EQUATION %d-----",i);
        printf("\n\tEnter your desired numerical coefficients for x, y and z\n\t\t\tthen the constant's value.\n\t   (Press enter each time you are done on your input.)\n");
        for(j=1;j<=n+1;j++)
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
    }
    clrscr();
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    x[i]=0;
    for(itr=1;itr<=maxit;itr++)
    {
        big=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            sum=0;
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(i!=j)
                    sum=sum+a[i][j]*x[j];
            }
            temp=(a[i][n+1]-sum)/a[i][i];
            relerror=fabs((x[i]-temp)/temp);
            if(relerror>big)
                big=relerror;
            x[i]=temp;

        }

        if(big<=e)
        {
            printf("\t  k\t      x\t    y\t    z\t    xe\t    ye\t    et\n");
            printf("\t  %d",itr);
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            printf("\t %.4f",x[i]);
            printf(" %.4f",sum);

            printf(" %.4f",big);

            while(itr>1)
            {
                itr=--itr;
                printf("\n\t  %d",itr);}
                getch();
                exit(1);

            }

        }
        printf("Does not converge in %d iteration \n",maxit);
        getch();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the contents of x in a debugger?  How many items does it contain?

Comment: I think the problem is at the last FOR LOOP. But i don't know how to fix it. Sorry I'm just a beginner in programming.:(

Comment: @BossJeric: Please tag your question as either C or C++, not both. ([see the tag wiki for details](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info))

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your print statements are outside of your for loop.  If you are trying to print the values at each iteration you need to have something like the following:

```
for(int iter; iter<maxit; iter++){
  /*** DO STUFF ***/
  if(big <= e){
      /*** PRINT STUFF ***/
  }
}/* end of for iter<maxit */
```

If you are not already using an IDE such as Eclipse, Visual studio, or even Emacs/Vi, I suggest you start.  These editors often have parenthises highlighting/matching so you can easily catch these things.

Comment: yes, you are right. I actually want to print the values of x,y and z on each iteration.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it may have been edited so that the print statement is in your iteration loop.  You have an exit command which I do not understand within your `if (big<=e)` branch which may be your problem.  User 120115 seems to have much more detail, I would look at it.

Comment: I don't know how to put his codes to my program. Will you help me? PLEASE? :(

Comment: Use a debugger.  Step through your code.  Figure out where you algorithm is doing something wrong.  I cannot write your code for you, sorry.